# Editar AbstractUser Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

estoy creando unos usuarios con Django y me he topado con que una cosa que le pasa a mucha gente, el caso es que me hace falta dos tipos de usuarios distintos,  y utilizar  `AbstractUser` es la opción mas acertada, pero hay un campo en particular que me sobra y es el campo `username` , he visto en Django que hay una forma de extender esta clase  es crear una relación `OneToOne` , y si bien no esta mal ya que lo implementaré, en mi caso quiero anular, o eliminar ese campo ( `username`) ya que no tiene mucha lógica en mi registro de usuario.

Ademas de esto no quiero tener que reescribir esta clase desde el principio con `BaseAbstractUser` ya que no quiero tocar algo que esta bien hecho.

Cualquier consejo de alguien que tenga experiencia trabajando con Django es bien recibido, gracias!

codigo:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField('Email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField('Numero de telefono', max_length=9, unique=True)
    
    #THIS IS THE LIST OF GENDERS
    MoW = [('Hombre', "Hombre"), ("Mujer","Mujer"), ("Ninguno","Ninguno")]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=7 ,choices=MoW, null=False)

    #THE PROFILE PHOTO
    userPhoto = models.ImageField()
   
   #IS NORMAL USER OR PARTNER OF THE APP
    Is_Partner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #THIS FIELDS JUST MAKESURE THE USER IS NOT ADMIN-PAGE
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    username = None
   
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name', 'phoneNumber', 'gender']
```

error:

```
self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes eliminar el campo `username` del modelo `AbstractUser` de la siguiente manera:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
```

Pero daría error por el atributo [`USERNAME_FIELD`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD), antes la documentación de Django de dicho atributo:

> Es una cadena que describe el nombre del campo en el modelo de usuario
> que se utiliza como identificador único. Por lo general, será un
> nombre de usuario de algún tipo, pero también puede ser una dirección
> de correo electrónico o cualquier otro identificador único. **El campo
> debe ser único (es decir, estar `unique=True`definido en su definición)**,
> a menos que utilice un backend de autenticación personalizado que
> admita nombres de usuario no únicos.
>
> En el siguiente ejemplo, el campo `identifierse` utiliza como campo de
> identificación:
>
> ```
> class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
>     identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
>     ...
>     USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'
> ```

Y por defecto el atributo [`USERNAME_FIELD`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) tiene como valor `'username'`, por eso al eliminar dicho atributo da error, solo habría que remplazarlo por el campo que requieras:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = '<field_name>'
```

Y listo, no debería dar ningún error.

---

#### Actualización:

Viendo el código fuente del manager `UserManager` [ [código fuente](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L129) ], pues no esta preparado para crear usuarios sin el campo `username`, entonces hay que modificarlo:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, username=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username=None, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return super().create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username=None, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return super().create_superuser(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Lo que hice, es que el argumento posicional `username` no sea requerido, así no es necesario pasarlo, ademas dicho argumento no se utiliza en lo absoluto, no tiene utilidad, pero lo hice de esta manera para evitar repetir código.

También modifique como tal la creación del usuario, en el método `_create_user`, ya que al momento de crear la instancia, se pasaba `username` como argumento de palabra clave (lo cual daría error) y también habían operaciones especificas para el campo `username`, que en este caso sobraban.

Y listo, con estas modificaciones al manager, no deberían haber inconvenientes o errores.

Comment: Esto no crearía un campo en blanco en mi tabla de usuario? (Dentro de mi base de datos), es por eso que dudo si usar AbstractUser o AbstractBaseUser, ya que no creo que sea muy recomendable dejar un campo en blanco en una BBDD

Comment: Claro que no deja un campo en blanco en la db, el "campo" `username` ni siquiera es un campo, es un simple atributo que tiene como valor `None`, esto es Python, no Django... ademas, si un atributo no es una instancia de una `Field` clase, ni siquiera es considerado un campo, es decir no se crea ningun "campo en blanco" en la tabla.

Comment: Tienes razon jaja xD, un gusto ayudarte

Comment: al final cambiare la estructura de AbstractBaseUser, ya que al intentar crear un superusuario por consola me obliga a tener el campo username, lo edito por si alguien tiene la misma duda!

Comment: Eso no deberia pasar, parece ser que no modificaste el atributo `USERNAME_FIELD`.

Comment: te enseño el codigo

Comment: Mmmm si esta bien el modelo, pero al parecer el problema es el `Manager`, hay que modificarlo para que funcione correctamente sin ese campo,  ya actualizare mi respuesta, dame tiempo xD

Comment: perfecto, gracias , justo ahora estaba leyendo algo acerca del manager

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Comment: Muy bueno, eso si maneja por completo el problema!